# Angular Service Workers not work on iOS standalone mode

Tags: ios, angular, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

I am working on PWA with Ionic v4 and Angular PWA service workers. On app.component.ts have a injected service to check if updates are available on PWA and then download and reload.

When I open PWA with the browser the service works fine and If I deploy an update the service worker update the cached PWA and ‘auto-reload’ the page.

The problem comes with PWA/standalone mode, on iOS when the PWA is added to homescreen it not refreshes anymore even killing it with the task app list. Only If I shutdown the device and on again it refreshes the state of the app. On Android devices all works as expected on PWA mode.

**This is my version checker service implemented with Angular service worker:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {SwUpdate} from '@angular/service-worker';

@Injectable()
export class LogUpdateService {

    constructor(updates: SwUpdate) {
        console.warn('check')
        updates.available.subscribe(event => {
            console.log('current version is', event.current);
            console.log('available version is', event.available);
            updates.activateUpdate().then(() => {
                console.warn('downloaded')
                document.location.reload();
            });
        });
        updates.activated.subscribe(event => {
            console.log('old version was', event.previous);
            console.log('new version is', event.current);
        });
    }
}
```

**This is my package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/pwa": "0.13.8",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/service-worker": "7.2.12",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.2.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "ionic2-calendar": "^0.5.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "serve": "^10.1.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "7.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.9",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "1.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~11.11.3",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.24",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.3",
    "tslint": "~5.14.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {}
    }
  }
```

Any Idea with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found is to code a javascript function (e.g. updateiOS()) that will do the following

1- Verify if we are running on iOS standalone mode (if not then don't continue)

2- Check for a new version on the server and reload page if we found a new version (make sure this https request is not cached!)

3- Save the last check time in a variable (e.g. var lastCheckTime)

And in my main javascript function, I will create a listener for "focus" event that will check the difference between now and lastCheckTime, if it's more than let's say 1 day then call updateiOS()

so far the focus event is working fine with me

Comment: what do you mean by call `updateiOS` function, do I need to call some method somewhere? Please elaborate